# How to add tag in dropdown menu to some selected categories

Tags: magento, php

I'm working on magento, and i have used webandpeople extension to customize display of my categories in dropdown list, i want to add some tags like new to some categories, plz provide me details how to do.... it
this is display of my website

[image]

I want to display something like

[image]

Comment: Add a category attribute

Comment: A category attribute should do it. Have you tried it?